# Getting only one value in xcode URL Scheme

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, appdelegate

I have my webpage coded where I have this link `myApp://loginInfo/abcd/123` and it opens my iOS app and it is opening it but issue is that my method which I have in `AppDelegate` only show one value which is "loginInfo" but I have 3 values in it I need to get all three values please help. here is my code in app.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
    NSString *text = [[url host] stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Data Received : %@", text);
    return YES;
}
```

OutPut:

```
Data Received : loginInfo
```

Comment: How about the `[url path]`, can you print it? You can get `[[url path] componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"]`.

Comment: sure, its "Data Received : (
    loginInfo
)"

Comment: Sorry, the `[url path]`. I made mistake.

Comment: Great now i am getting "Data Received : (
    "",
    "abcd,
    123
)" how can i save both string separately?

Comment: Thank you. Post you Answer i will mark it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `[[url path] componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"]`, you can get the parameters seperately.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to get your three values from your custom url :

```
    NSLog(@"URL scheme:%@", [url scheme]);//myApp
    NSLog(@"URL query: %@", [url query]);//loginInfo/abcd/123

    NSArray* foo = [[url query] componentsSeparatedByString: @"/"];
    NSLog(@"my query %@",foo);

    NSString* firstBit = [foo objectAtIndex: 0];
    ....
```